# Task list and giving custom permissions to task assignee

Tags: tasks, task-list

I have got a list with a lot of task. The first column of the list contains the name of the task while the following ones are additional information.

As now I have defined a "task Creator" role/user - ie only a specific user can create new tasks or manage the existing ones. I have also the requirement to define a procedure that would allows a specific user to be defined as "owners/assignee" of a task so that he will be able to modify its data.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this result?

Ideally the assignee should be able to edit only a specific subset of the task info.

Comment: Reworded the question to be more clear. Still, a key point is missing: who will define an user as the assignee? It is a prerogative of the task Creator or any user can claim a task for his own?

Comment: The Person who created task should propagate edit/delete rules to user who take the task to solve